# Openssl aes-256-cbc encryption

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes, pbkdf2, cbc-mode

I am trying to perform a file encryption which is equal to the below command of openssl:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -e -salt -pbkdf2 -iter 10000 -in geometry.json -out geometry.json.enc -pass pass:"password"
```

I am using the implementation 'not-yet-commons-ssl:not-yet-commons-ssl:0.3.13'

With the default values after the file encryption the decryption from openssl command line always throws up the below error;

```
40B7B9B5F37F0000:error:1C800064:Provider routines:ossl_cipher_unpadblock:bad decrypt:../providers/implementations/ciphers/ciphercommon_block.c:124:
```

What do I need to pass to the openssl encrypt function?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: presumably http://devdoc.net/javamisc/not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3.17 which is Java code -- but OP: that code was last updated in 2015 (0.3.13 presumably even earlier) and in 2015 OpenSSL did not yet have `enc -pbkdf2` (it also defaulted `enc` to EVP_BytesToKey with md5; only 1.1.0 in 2016 up default to sha256)

Answer (score 0):

Salt is used by default, so you don't need to use it explicitly. I would use higher iteration number with pbkdf2, or in this case, it would make more sense to use sha256 instead of pbkdf2. Also, there is no reason to use quotation marks around your password. `pass:"password"` should be `pass:password` unless quotations are part of the password.

You could use this:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -pass pass:password -in geometry.json -out geometry.json.enc -pbkdf2 -iter 100000
```

or this:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -k password -in geometry.json -out geometry.json.enc -pbkdf2 -iter 100000
```

And if you want to use SHA-256 for password hashing then you could use this:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -k password -in geometry.json -out geometry.json.enc -md sha256
```

Comment: FWIW all versions of OpenSSL that support `enc -pbkdf2` (1.1.1 and 3.0) already default to sha256 for 'traditional' (non-pbkdf2) `EVP_BytesToKey`